# Optimising eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a need to attach a custom select on an eloquent query, but I find the whole thing a bit hard to understand. This regards a forum system where each Forum object needs to know how many Topic relations and Comment relations are registered. This is what I've got so far:

**in Forum.php**

```
public function getNumTopics () {
    return Topic::where('forum_id', '=', $this->id)->count();
}

public function getNumComments () {
    return Comment::wherein('topic_id', Topic::where('forum_id', '=', 1)->lists('id'));
}
```

**Controller returning json**

```
public function getCategories () {
    $categories = ForumCategory::with('forums')->get();
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if ($cat->forums->count() > 0) {
            foreach ($cat->forums as $forum) {
                /* @var $forum Forum */
                $forum->num_topics = $forum->getNumTopics();
                $forum->num_posts  = $forum->getNumComments();
            }
        }
    }
    return Response::json($categories, 200);
}
```

The call takes approx 1300ms to return 5 Forums in three categories. I suspect this is because this executes around 16 queries instead of one. Is there a way to attach the "num_topics" an "num_posts" as properties on select, so that I only execute one query?

**Edit**

What I basically want is for Eloquent to produce something like this when I ask for `Forum::all()`:

```
select f.*,
       ifnull(count(t.id), 0) num_topics,
       ifnull(count(c.id), 0) num_posts
  from forums f left join topics t on t.forum_id = f.id
                left join comments c on c.topic_id = t.id
 group by f.id
```

Comment: The first thing I'd try to optimize is the getNumComments function, which runs two queries. Also your getNumtTopics and getNumComments both run essentially the same query, `Topic::where('forum_id'...`

Comment: I've added the query I think I want Eloquent to produce for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to query those tables either way so your best bet should be to just eager load everything and count it after it's been retrieved instead of making more calls to the database just to find a count.

```
public function getCategories () {
    $categories = ForumCategory::with('forums.topics.comments')->get();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        foreach($category->forums as &$forum) {
            $forum->num_topics = $forum->topics()->count();
            $forum->num_comments = 0;
            foreach($forum->topics as $topic) {
                $forum->num_comments += $topic->comments()->count();
            }
        }
    }

    return Response::json($categories, 200);
}
```

This will attach `num_topics` and `num_comments` to each `Forum` object.

It's fewer calls but it's grabbing more information in one sweep so it may be faster or slower, will have to do some testing.  The good news is that because it's grabbing everything, no additional queries should be needed.

Comment: For large datasets (which this might become), querying out all levels like this might be a bit excessive? Or is Laravel doing some inside optimizations I'm not aware of here? See the query I'm looking to produce in my question edit above

Comment: As far as performance goes, the routine you posted is approx 50ms faster and responds in 1250ms instead of 1300. Which is not that rewarding... :-( But I'm all for fewer calls though...